# dynamically change background color listView

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to change background color of list view dynamically based on string value (JSON). I want to change the background color if the text in the TAG_SEVERITY field is "critical". Below is how I tried, but With code it changes the severity field to blue regardless of the text. I t would be etter if the row color is changed instead of field background color. I'm quite new to this.

```
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
            R.layout.single_post, new String[] {TAG_SEVERITY, TAG_TITLE }, new int[] { R.id.severity, R.id.rTitle});adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            int v=view.getId();
            if(v==R.id.severity && String.valueOf(data.toString()).contentEquals("Critical")){
                ((View) view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            TextView TV=(TextView) view;
            TV.setText(data.toString());
            return true;
        }
    });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see why it enters the if statement when you think it shouldn't? Is the value of the string always critical for some reason?

Comment: I,ve chacked Json string and its not always "critical"

Comment: but what about with a break point at the time the if statement executes?

Answer (score 1):

I think that by setting the background for the view.getParent(), you are setting the background for the entire ListView. Have you tried using just view.setBackground()?

The other alternative is to create your own adapter class, and setting the view's background color in the getView() method based on the severity.

Comment: Will try that but String.valueOf(data.toString()).contentEquals("Critical") is not working. any idea?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, is it returning a syntax error, runtime error, or a logic error in this case?

Comment: No it runs but the "severity" field is blue irrespective of the text.

Comment: So, to me it seems like your ListView has a text and a sub-text, where the text is the severity level and the sub-text is more information about the item? Also, where in the code is this snippet from? onCreate()?

Comment: It's on Resume() and JSON text receives to TAG_SEVERITY and is displayed at R.id.severity.

Comment: You may want to debug the code and check that the string you are testing is actually holding the correct information. Also there could be an odd space or something, but otherwise im not sure, sorry for the unhelpfulness.